# Calling Singleton Class Methods Inside Open Singleton Class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm trying to understand why I can't call methods defined on the singleton class from within the open class but I can from the actual class.

Can someone explain why the first example fails and the second one doesn't?

```
class One
  class << self
    def one; end
    one
  end
end

NameError (undefined local variable or method 'one' for #<Class:One>)

class Two
  class << self
    def one; end
  end

  self.one
end

=> nil
```

Comment: I think (and someone correct me if I am wrong) the metaclass idiom is more like a module extension than an inheritance pattern e.g. `module One; def one; end; end` then `class Two; extend One; end` in this case `One` does not have a method `one` however via extension `Two` does. Thus `One.one #=> NoMethodError` however `Two.one` works fine

Answer (score 2):

Your example is more confusing than it needs to be. It doesn't require a singleton class at all:

```
class Foo
  def bar; end

  bar # NameError
end

Foo.new.bar
```

Here, we have a class `Foo` with an instance method `bar`. A singleton class is still just a class, so this is actually the exact same example as yours.

`def` without an explicit definee defines an instance method of the closest lexically enclosing class definition, in this case `Foo`. A message send without an explicit receiver like `bar` sends the message to `self`. Inside the class definition body, `self` is the class itself.

So, `def bar` defines an *instance method* in `Foo`, i.e. a method you can call on *instances* of `Foo`.

`bar` inside the class definition body sends a message to `self`, which is `Foo`. Since `Foo` is not an instance of itself, it does not have a method named `bar`, ergo, the method call fails.

This works exactly the same with a singleton class, since it is still just a class.

Answer (score 0):

You made the wrong assumption about where the method belongs to, in the first place. The call to the instance method `one` from inside class context should not succeed. In your first snippet, you try to call method `one` from the singleton class of the singleton class of `One` (because it’s called from `singleton_class` context).

Example with normal class / instance methods to clarify:

```
class One
  def self.one()
    puts :class
  end
  def one
    puts :instance
  end
  one()
end
#⇒ class
```

So, the expected behavior would be *to raise* `NameError`. Now the answer is simple: it raises `NameError` because this method does not exist.